Possibility to select Information from a text in Make
can you help me please with an issue in the app Make? I am trying to select from an e-mail full of text concrete information - e-mail, phone number etc., anyway Make inserts me only the whole text from the e-mail. How to solve it? I tried to find some extentions in Make, anyway I can only withdraw the whole text from the e-mail.

I think you may be talking about the "make" product from make.com.  You should use the tag [make.com] not [makefile].  The [makefile] tag is for the POSIX program make which is a completely different thing.

Hi, thanks for the comment, I have the tag make.com, so I think it is correct.

You didn't have the make.com tag when I posted my comment.  Renaud edited your question and fixed it for you by removing makefile and adding make.com.
